# PHP Mailer Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, php, html

Mailer PHP

```
 <?PHP 
    $to = "phil@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Results from your Request Info form";
    $headers = "From: Form Mailer";
    $forward = 0;
    $location = "";

    $date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
    $time = date ("h:i A");



    $msg = "Below is the result of your feedback form. It was submitted on $date at $time.\n";
    $msg2 = "Below is the result of your feedback form. It was submitted on $date at $time.<br>";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";
            $msg2 .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";
            $msg2 .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "<br>";
        }
    }

    $sentmail = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    if($sentmail){
    echo "Email Has Been Sent .";
    }
    else {
    echo "Cannot Send Email. The message that would have been sent is:<br>";
    echo $msg2;

    }

    if ($forward == 1) {
        header ("Location:$location");
    }
    else {
        echo "Thank you for submitting our form. We will get back to you as soon as possible.";
    }

    ?>
```

Contact US Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Contact us" />

    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MOstylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
.mapcenter img{display: block;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border: 1px solid lightgray}
h3 {text-align: center; width: 60%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
</style>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm()
{
    if(document.getElementById("p1").value=="")
    {
        alert("Hi! Your name is required for submission.")
        document.getElementById("p1").focus();
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("p2").value=="")
    {
        alert("Hi! Your email is required for submission.")
    }
    else
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function changeBack()
    {
        document.getElementById("b1").style.backgroundColor="rgba(205, 24, 24,1)";
    }

    function changeUp()
    {
        document.getElementById("b1").style.backgroundColor="rgba(205, 24, 24,0.75)";
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="mailer.php" onsubmit="return processForm()">

        <div class="background">

        <div class="header" id="myHeader">
        <div class="ahover">
        <table>
        <tr id="i2">
            <th> <a href="inventory.htm">INVENTORY </a> </th>
            <th> <a href="pastsales.htm">PAST SALES </a> </th>
            <th> <a href="sell.htm"> SELLING</a> </th>
            <th> <a href="index.htm"><img src="MOround.png" id="i1" alt="logo" width="120" height="120"></a></th>
            <th> <a href="aboutus.htm">ABOUT US </a> </th>
            <th> <a href="ContactUs.htm">CONTACT US</a> </th>
            <th> <a href="events.htm">EVENTS</a> </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>

        <h1>Let's Connect!</h1>

    <table>
                <tr><td>Your Name: <input id="p1" type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="100" placeholder="First & Last"></td>
          <td>Your Email: <input id="p2" type="text" name="email" maxlength="100" placeholder="@"></td>
          <td>Your Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="100" placeholder="123-456-7890"></td></tr>

    </table>

    <br>
    <br>

    <table>

                <tr> <td> <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Your Note" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea> </td></tr>
</table>
<div class="display">
    <input type="submit" onmouseover="changeUp()" onmouseout="changeBack()" id="b1"class="button" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
</div>
        <br>
      <h3>Click on the map for our phone number and the pointer for directions to our warehouse:</h3>
        <div class="linkhover">
        <div class="mapcenter">
            <img id="img1" src="homelogos/googlemap.png" usemap="#image-map" >

    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="_blank" alt="warehouse" title="warehouse" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//210+Kuniholm+Dr+%236,+Holliston,+MA+01746/@42.2292264,-71.4641604,13z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x89e477ab59a7f13b:0x61314ee92acc8e13!2m2!1d-71.4290551!2d42.2291682" coords="121,397,258,506" shape="rect">
    </map>
</div>
</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <h5> Copyright</h5>
        <h6> Beta Release 4: 06/05/18</h6>
</form>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
        document.getElementById("i1").width="80";
        document.getElementById("i1").height="80";
        document.getElementById("i2").style.fontSize="14px"
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
        document.getElementById("i1").width="120";
        document.getElementById("i1").height="120";
        document.getElementById("i2").style.fontSize="16px"
  }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not receiving any emails upon submission. The submission works with statements coming from the php document confirming that email has been sent;however, the actual email is never received. I used the php mailer template from a class I had taken. The instructor stated that we just needed to edit the email field then add to our publicHTML and all would be well. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: In this line `$headers = "From: Form Mailer";` are you using a real mail address (username@domaine.tld)?

Comment: Have you looked at the php_mail log to see if the email is being sent? If it is then you may have delivery issues (marked as spam, failed SPF record checks, etc).

Comment: Remove the error suppressors. It doesn't help in debugging

Comment: Have you considered checking your junk folder?